# Как корректно построить фразу

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как корректно построить фразу "Пункты с 4 по 7 объединить в общУю нумерацию 4.1 4.2 )

Answer (score 1):

Фраза непонятна. Если вы хотите из 4 пунктов сделать 2, то: Пункты 4-5 и 6-7 объединить в подпункты 4.1 и 4.2. Если вы хотите просто изменить нумерацию, то: Нумерацию пунктов 4-7 заменить нумерацией 4.1-4.7.

Answer (score 0):

Тут действительно можно подумать о чем угодно.

Напишите, как это выглядит сейчас - и как оно мыслится поле реализации этого "объединить".

У меня такое ощущение, что Вы хотите либо из пунктов сделать подпункты, либо наоборот. 
Но сомневаюсь, поэтому вариантов не даю.